# In Alien, what were the Xenomorph's two mouths used for?

Tags: alien-franchise, xenomorph

The Xenomorphs in the Alien series had two mouths, one inside the other:

[image: Mouth within a mouth]

I remember the inner mouth being used to attack someone, but never any direct footage of the outer mouth being used. What was the purpose of the two mouths? Was this ever established, or was it simply left to our imaginations?

Comment: Outside the story, they were designed that way for maximum creepiness, not for sound biology.

Comment: Figured as much on that part. Primarily interested in reasons from the in-universe viewpoint.

Comment: So they can talk and eat at the same time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Wow - this lead me to some interesting links and info.  The direct answer is in the [Alien Species Wiki](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Species_Wiki).  In main [Xenomorph article](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Xenomorph) there's enough to figure this out.

In the [Biology Section](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Xenomorph#Biology) it points out that the "tongue mouth" or secondary jaws (or mouth) is what the Xenomorph eats with.  (So my original guess that the secondary one would hold the food is wrong - the large mouth holds it if needed.)  Even more, the [Secondary Jaws](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Xenomorph#Secondary_Jaws) can be used as a close-combat weapon.  It can be pushed out of the primary mouth or jaws with such force it can shatter skulls of some species.

What surprised me is that we have a species on Earth with something similar - the [Moray Eel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moray_Eel) also has a [Pharyngeal Jaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharyngeal_jaw).  It can't easily swallow, so it grabs prey and the smaller internal jaws, the pharyngeal jaw, then bit and pull the food into the gullet.

Comment: Excellent answer. Funnily enough, I remember David Attenborough mentioning the Xenomorph in a nature documentary in which Moray Eels were featured.

Comment: I want to add one major point to the question and to research: While I did find this in the wiki, we have discussed that many times and at least one moderator has pointed out that most wiki articles are so long and convoluted, that material being in a wiki does NOT make it general reference.  (It's VERY tough to sort through some wikis!)

Answer (score 1):

i think the inner mouth is a CQC (close quarters combat) weapon like the tail or claws but also the feeding mouth because the mouth is by the throat but if it wasn't there the outer mouth would be the main mouth but also the outer mouth might shield the inner mouth.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you have any sources or reasoning for this, or is it just your own opinion?